# Parsing 401 Error Description to decide which error occurred

Tags: c#, parsing

I am trying to do some server-side validation of client credentials (id and secret). The endpoint that I am using is an external API and requires both values and if either of them is incorrect, a `401` is thrown, along with an error object that has the form of:

```
{
    "error": "...",
    "error_description": "..."
}
```

Unfortunately, if either of the values is incorrect, instead of getting a constant key that I can use, I only get a message as a string. For example, an invalid `client_id` will yield:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Invalid value for 'client_id' parameter."
}
```

An invalid `client_secret` will also be a `401` with the `invalid_client` set as the `error` and the error message containing: `"The client secret supplied for a confidential client is invalid."`.

I was curious as to what would be the most elegant solution to deciding which error occurred. For testing, I was simply looking for a word in the description and sending back the corresponding error.

Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is coming from an external API. @mjwills

Comment: Is `error` the error code?

Comment: @John Presumably, but it is the same for both cases so it's not too helpful.

Comment: I don't think there's really an elegant solution to this if you have no control overt he API itself. If you're using `HttpClient` you can write a `HttpMessageHandler` so that you can parse them to a more meaningful response in a central place. Probably not very helpful, I guess.

Comment: The 401 is the status code in the http response.  I good response is 200 ok.  Instead of looking for words you can simply check to status number returned.  You can get a list of all response by searching the web.

Comment: @jdweng The problem is that for _both_ error cases, the status is `401`.

Comment: See following : https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/401-unauthorized-error